# How can I export multiple versions of a file from a single source?

Tags: gruntjs

I am looking for a simple solution that will allow me to have a single source html file, with some type of conditions setup so that grunt can export two distribution versions of the single file. Example:

Main source file: `src/index.html`

```
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <!-- SOME TYPE OF CONDITION -->
  <script src="script1.js"></script>
  <!-- OTHERWISE -->
  <script src="script2.js"></script>
```

Can I create two versions of the file:
`build/index1.html` that includes `script1`
`build/index2.html` that includes `script2`

I realize this is not ideal, but the project is actually much larger and includes more complicated details. I am learning gruntjs as I go so I want to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: Not quite sure your setup, but why don't you just have a build step that generates the file with different contents based on what your building? Like if you're doing one for production, build script.js with your production dependencies, if you're doing it for test, build it with the additional testing dependencies. Otherwise, if you're trying to make two builds with the same files just use some sort of html template compilation, for example you could use jade: http://jade-lang.com/reference/#conditionals and the grunt-contrib-jade plugin to pass different data into your template conditional

Comment: I actually need two versions for production. Version 1 would include a script, version 2 wouldn't. Later in the page, version 1 would include a script, where version 2 would actually embed the script inline on the page. I need one version that is pretty vanilla, and then a second version for use in a mobile application that needs inline js because of encoding issues and some other dependencies that version 1 doesn't need. Maybe a combination of https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-processhtml/ and https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-devcode/ ?

Comment: looks like grunt-devcode might do the trick for you for conditional blocks. For resource embedding (inlining) check out grunt-embed. I ended up having to re-write part of the task for my needs, so you could always take a look at that if you need it (if you need multiple source file support) https://github.com/andrewstucki/registration/blob/master/client/tasks/embed.coffee

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish the task with grunt-processhtml (https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-processhtml).

gruntfile:

```
processhtml: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      'build/default.html':['src/index.html']
    }   // files
  },    // dist
  custom: {
    files: {
      'build/index.html':['src/index.html']
    }
  }      // custom
},       // processhtml
```

Within the source index file there are conditionals that load different variables or content based on the grunt environment.